# Add mysql table column dynamically

Tags: mysql, database, dynamic, vb6

How to add table column in `mysql` **Dynamically**?

I have a `vb6` code and `mysql` as database.

Suppose I want to enter new column in the **textbox** then the value of **textbox** will be a **column** in mysql.

Is this possible? How to achieve this one?

Answer (score 3):

See [**ALTER TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) command for that.

But normally it is not a great idea to alter DB structure from your client application.

If you have to, this means that your DB is not very well designed.

You can always have a `dynamic data structure` presented in your statically structured DB tables set by using relationships between tables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible

Query for adding a new column to database is

"ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN " + textbox.Text + " VARCHAR(40)"

From VB you can use ADO for it